# Codingbat authoring java problems with 2D array test cases

Tags: java, arrays

I am teaching java programming and frequently assign [Codingbat.com](https://codingbat.com/java) problems.  Codingbat is a great tool for students to get practice.

I have authored some simple problems successfully, but I am stuck trying to create a Codingbat test case for a problem with a 2D array.  I have the reference code and 2D array declarations running in a java program, but cannot get the test cases to run in codingbat.

I have a method declaration:

```
public static int lSearch(int[][] arr, int key)
```

What I thought should be proper Codingbat test case:

> { {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36},  {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36 } },
>   31, 6

Results in the codingbat error message:

> Problem has publication warnings: Test case parse error line 1: [
>   {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36], [4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36 } ], 31, 6

I have tried many permutations of '{','}','[',']','(', and ')' without success.

I know this can be done because 2D array problems are available.  I just cant seem to find the key piece of information.

Comment: Surely you have code to accompany this error message?

Comment: The test is run by Codingbat, the error somehow is in the format of the test case.  If you are concerned about what submitted code to Codingbat would look like, a minimum case would be <br/>                                                                 public static int lSearch(int[][] arr, int key)  { return 6; }

Comment: Just to make sure you are understanding the question I am asking.  Writing java code to handle a 2D array is not the problem.  The question is about how to author a test case in codingbat to check java code.  My question is about Codingbat's test case syntax for 2D arrays.  Not about Java's syntax for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have one extra parameter which is not expected. What does 6 represent exactly in your case if 31 is the key?

Besides, as you can see in your error the parsing of 2D array is somehow incorrect, [{....], [....}] which does not make sense.

Comment: The codingbat test case is "{ {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36}, {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36 } }, 31, 6".  The trailing 6 is the expected result which is used by codingbat to confirm the result produced from the students submitted code.  I agree the " [{....], [....}] " does not make sense to me either, but that is the message produced by codingbat.

Comment: Just to make sure you are understanding the question I am asking. Writing java code to handle a 2D array is not the problem. The question is about how to author a test case in codingbat to check java code. My question is about Codingbat's test case syntax for 2D arrays. Not about Java's syntax for 2D arrays.  Check out Codingbat authoring docs "https://codingbat.com/authoring.html#problem"

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before. For some reason I can't manage to put two dimensional arrays for my case either, but you can try turning the argument into a string. It works through the website, but it may require extra steps for the student to convert the string into the 2d array altogether.

Instead of this:

```
{ {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36}, {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36 } }, 31, 6
```

Try this :

```
"{ {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36}, {4,7,23,43,19,78,31,11,29,36 } }", 31, 6
```

If there are any better alternatives ill let you know.